# How can i reset my Libre Office Calc setting

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I am using **Libre** Office Calc for my Excel work.

**Image 1:**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

I can not see the format color in on `Libre office` installed @My System.

but on my Colleague System who uses the same Libre Office i can see the Format color.

I must have accidentally done some format changes, how can i get it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have **View - Value Highlighting** option as off.

**[Here is the Link to explain more.](https://help.libreoffice.org/scalc/.uno:ViewValueHighlighting?Language=en-US&System=WIN&Version=4.0#bm_id3145068)**

That did solve my problem.